# React Table Generation Issue: Array.fill() vs. Array.from()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I'm attempting to create a table generator in React using the provided code. I'm curious about why it doesn't work as expected. When I replace Array().fill with Array.from(), it functions correctly. I understand that there might be an issue with Array.fill(), but it works in some situations. Additionally, when rendering it with a pure generator, it also functions as expected. However, it doesn't work when I attempt to render it through a submit action.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [rowInput, setRowInput] = useState(0);
  const [colInput, setColInput] = useState(0);
  const [submitInput, setSubmitInput] = useState([]);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setSubmitInput([rowInput, colInput]);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(submitInput);
  }, [submitInput]);

  return (
    <div className='wrapper'>
      <div className='inputSection'>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div>
            <label htmlFor='rowInput'>Rows: <input id='rowInput' type='number' value={rowInput} onChange={e => setRowInput(e.target.value)} /></label>
          </div>
          <div>
            <label htmlFor='colInput'>Cols: <input id='colInput' type='number' value={colInput} onChange={e => setColInput(e.target.value)} /></label>
          </div>
          <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <GenerateTable rows={submitInput[0]} cols={submitInput[1]}/>
    </div>
  )
} // this doesn' work
```

but this work

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const row = 4;
  const col = 6;

  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        {
          Array(row).fill(null).map((_, rowIdx) => (
            <tr key={rowIdx}>
              {
                Array(col).fill(null).map((_, colIdx) => (
                  <td key={colIdx}>
                    {'1'}
                  </td>
                ))
              }

            </tr>
          ))
        }
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your first code block does not appear related to your question? So: can you describe what you're trying to _do_? Because this looks like a very strange way to generate a table given that you're not _using_ the array for anything, you're kind of _abusing_ it to get a counter that goes from 0 to row/col, so: just use a `for` loop. That's what they're for. Construct the table body before your return statement and template _that_ in, instead?

Comment: Maybe because `Array.fill` and `Array.from` do different things?

Comment: Furthermore *"doesn't work as expected"* is not a proper problem description. Describe the current and the expected behaviour ... And you say, when you *"replace `Array.fill` with `Array.from`  it functions correctly", yet in your question, you label the code with `Array.fill` as working?